# Это странное слово "минералОг"

Tags: орфоэпия

Биология - биОлог, экология - экОлог, а вот минералогия - минералОГ. **Странно как-то звучит это слово и напоминает нечто  неодушевленное: монолОг, пролОг, диалОг.**

Раньше форма "минерОлог" использовалась и даже была отмечена в словарях. Интересное замечание есть в словаре у Аванесова: **минералОГ, не рек! минерАлог, минерОлог.** Значит, делались попытки смещения ударения на основу (минерАлог) и перегласовки (минерОлог).

**Примеры:**

**МИНЕРОЛОГ**. минеролога, м. (разг.). То же, что минералог. Ушаков. Толковый словарь русского языка Ушакова. 2012.

Геолог пользуется камерой для фотографирования строения земной коры, **минеролог** с помощью микро-фотографии изучает шлифты камней, ботаник фотографирует сообщества и отдельные экземпляры растений, зоолог ― животных; так можно без конца перечислять все отрасли человеческого знания. [А. Бианки. Фотография на службе естествознания // «Советское фото», 1926]

Выдающийся русский ученый, **минеролог**, геохимик, академик АН СССР, Александр Евгеньевич Ферсман внес значительный вклад в формирование минерально-сырьевой базы страны.

**И вопросы:**   (1) Есть ли еще в русском языке названия лиц, занимающих я наукой, с окончанием на ударный ЛОГ?  (2) Должна ли фонетика слова как-то выражать его семантику?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Есть ли еще в русском языке названия лиц, занимающихся наукой, с
>   окончанием на ударный ЛОГ?

Есть: [***генеалОг.***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3&all=x)

Comment: Да, генеало́гия (др.-греч. γενεαλογία — родословная, от γενεά (genea) — «семья» и λόγος (logos) — «слово, знание»). Кстати, это слово легко "подкорректировать": генеология, генеолог, только вот греки могут обидеться. Вот интересное высказывание: "Признаюсь, не нравится мне это слово. По мне так лучше "родословие". Но что поделаешь, если в эпоху повального англоязычия мы часто забываем наш богатый и красивый русский язык и запросто произносим чужие, порой РЕЖУЩИЕ СЛУХ СЛОВА". http://gorbunov.web-box.ru/main/genealogy. Правда, частотноть у этого слова невелика, в отличие от минералОга

Comment: А вот  физиоло́гия (греч. physis природа + logos учение,  φύσις — природа и λόγος — знание) ), откуда здесь О?  Это соединительная гласная?

Answer (score 1):

Биолог, геолог, физиолог, технолог, криптолог, маркетолог... В одной минералогии  буква А стоит, наверно, поэтому и минералОг.

Comment: Везде делается смещение ударения (биология - биолог), и перегласовка - обычное явление в языке (смотреть - рассматривать), почему бы не разрешить форму "минерОлог" со смещением и перегласовкой, а то "минералОг" как-то напрягает слух, кажется искусственным.

Comment: Sibylla Это не перегласовка. Здесь смысл потеряется.